# Get bootstrap radio button text - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm using bootstrap and I find it confusing when trying to extract the label name. How do I get the selected label text? (e.g. Furniture or Fruits)

```
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">
     <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="myval1" /></span>
     <input class="form-control" value="Furniture" disabled>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">
     <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="myval2" /></span>
     <input class="form-control" value="Fruits" disabled>
</div>
```

I tried these but did not give the label text:

```
alert($(  $(":radio[name=radioGroup]:checked").prop("labels") ).text());


alert($('input[name="radioGroup"]:checked').text());


alert($('input[name="radioGroup"]:checked + label').text());
```

Comment: [Here, have a cookie](http://jsfiddle.net/k49y4ebg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario you just need to get the value of `selected` radio button.
For your better understanding have a lookto this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/356/) link

You can use the selected DOM element as::

```
alert($("input[name='radioGroup']:checked").closest(".input-group").find(".form-control").val())
```

Comment: Nice... How do I refer to `name="radioGroup" `? Because there are many radio button groups on the page?

Comment: @Anne Here you can check http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/355/

its using name='radioGroup'

Comment: Thanks. Is it nessassary to use `.find()` ? Can't I t be done  as `$("input[name='radioGroup']:checked").val()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
$('input[name="radioGroup"]:checked').parents('.input-group').find('.form-control').val()
```

OR

```
$('input[name="radioGroup"]:checked').parent().next().val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .val() then follow the tree from the checkbox up to its containing div and back down to the value in the associated input.

```
alert($("input[name=radioGroup]:checked").parent(".input-group-addon").parent(".input-group").children("input.form-control").val());
```